# Squid is extremly slow (20+ secs delay)

Tags: proxy, squid

I was forced to ask question here as i am out of ideas.. After server restart Squid started to act weird..

I did TCPDump and i got this in like 15 seconds :

61122 packets captured
62148 packets received by filter
1026 packets dropped by kernel

This is part of output from tcpdump :

```
15:16:44.275135 IP (tos 0x10, ttl 64, id 783, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 388)
10.35.9.55.ssh > 10.32.34.225.47136: Flags [P.], cksum 0x41d1 (incorrect -> 0xccac), seq 19500768:19501104, ack 2401, win 350, options [nop,nop,TS val 531206376 ecr 2163128164], length 336
```

15:16:44.275217 IP (tos 0x10, ttl 64, id 784, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 388)
    10.35.9.55.ssh > 10.32.34.225.47136: Flags [P.], cksum 0x41d1 (incorrect -> 0x0bfc), seq 19501104:19501440, ack 2401, win 350, options [nop,nop,TS val 531206376 ecr 2163128164], length 336
15:16:44.275295 IP (tos 0x10, ttl 64, id 785, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 260)
    10.35.9.55.ssh > 10.32.34.225.47136: Flags [P.], cksum 0x4151 (incorrect -> 0xb22a), seq 19501440:19501648, ack 2401, win 350, options [nop,nop,TS val 531206376 ecr 2163128164], length 208
15:16:44.314674 IP (tos 0x10, ttl 63, id 62262, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    10.32.34.225.47136 > 10.35.9.55.ssh: Flags [.], cksum 0x82f2 (correct), ack 19501648, win 1465, options [nop,nop,TS val 2163128205 ecr 531206375], length 0
15:16:44.841888 STP 802.1d, Config, Flags [none], bridge-id 8135.a0:cf:5b:57:26:80.8002, length 42
    message-age 1.00s, max-age 20.00s, hello-time 2.00s, forwarding-delay 15.00s
    root-id 8135.a0:cf:5b:57:10:00, root-pathcost 4
15:16:44.951774 IP (tos 0x10, ttl 63, id 62263, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 100)
    10.32.34.225.47136 > 10.35.9.55.ssh: Flags [P.], cksum 0x3f0f (correct), seq 2401:2449, ack 19501648, win 1465, options [nop,nop,TS val 2163128842 ecr 531206375], length 48
15:16:44.951868 IP (tos 0x10, ttl 63, id 62264, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 100)
    10.32.34.225.47136 > 10.35.9.55.ssh: Flags [P.], cksum 0xf931 (correct), seq 2449:2497, ack 19501648, win 1465, options [nop,nop,TS val 2163128842 ecr 531206375], length 48
15:16:44.951935 IP (tos 0x10, ttl 64, id 786, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    10.35.9.55.ssh > 10.32.34.225.47136: Flags [.], cksum 0x81ca (correct), ack 2497, win 350, options [nop,nop,TS val 531207053 ecr 2163128842], length 0
15:16:44.952052 IP (tos 0x10, ttl 64, id 787, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 228)
    10.35.9.55.ssh > 10.32.34.225.47136: Flags [P.], cksum 0x4131 (incorrect -> 0xf45f), seq 19501648:19501824, ack 2497, win 350, options [nop,nop,TS val 531207053 ecr 2163128842], length 176

Comment: In the mess above i saw "message-age 1.00s, max-age 20.00s, hello-time 2.00s, forwarding-delay 15.00s" ,not sure where is that defined .. I tried various tweaking from other forums yet none work..
TCPDump output seems like overload/ddos to same client. Any suggestions ? Best regards.

Answer (score -2):

Problem is fixed,it was DNS related.